# How do I split the dataset into number of folds(here, 3) based on their index and run classifier algorithm with differnt values of the hyperparameter

Tags: python, numpy, validation

I am running a RandomSearch cross validation on the KNN classifier model with k-fold cross validation. Without using any libraries I wish to split my dataset into 3 (folds). Now, we will have 3 groups of data. I want to make (group 1 + group 2),(group 1 + group 3),(group 2 + group 3) as training data and group 3, group 2 and group 3 as test data respectively.

```
x,y = make_classification(n_samples=10000, n_features=2, n_informative=2, n_redundant= 0, n_clusters_per_class=1, random_state=60)
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(x,y,stratify=y,random_state=42)

def RandomSearchCV(x_train,y_train,classifier, param_range, folds):
  group1_x=X_train[0:int(len(X_train)/folds)]
  group2_x=X_train[int(len(X_train)/folds):2*int(len(X_train)/folds)]
  group3_x=X_train[0:int(len(X_train)/folds)]
  group1_y=y_train[0:int(len(y_train)/folds)]
  group2_y=y_train[int(len(y_train)/folds):2*int(len(y_train)/folds)]
  group3_y=y_train[0:int(len(y_train)/folds)]
  cv1_train_x=np.concatenate((group1_x,group2_x))
  cv1_test_x=group3_x
  cv1_train_y=np.concatenate((group1_y,group2_y))
  cv1_test_y=group3_y
  cv2_train_x=np.concatenate((group1_x,group3_x))
  cv2_test_x=group2_x
  cv2_train_y=np.concatenate((group1_y,group3_y))
  cv2_test_y=group2_y
  cv3_train_x=np.concatenate((group2_x,group3_x))
  cv3_test_x=group1_x
  cv3_train_y=np.concatenate((group2_y,group3_y))
  cv3_test_y=group1_y
  trainscores=[]
  testscores=[]
  for k in tqdm(params['n_neighbors']):
    trainscores_folds=[]
    testscores_folds=[]
    for j in range(0,folds):
      classifier.n_neighbors=k
      classifier.fit(cv1_train_x,cv1_train_y)
      Y_predicted = classifier.predict(cv1_test_x)
      testscores_folds.append(accuracy_score(cv1_test_y, Y_predicted))
      Y_predicted = classifier.predict(cv1_train_x)
      trainscores_folds.append(accuracy_score(cv1_train_y, Y_predicted))
      #
      classifier.fit(cv2_train_x,cv2_train_y)
      Y_predicted = classifier.predict(cv2_test_x)
      testscores_folds.append(accuracy_score(cv2_test_y, Y_predicted))
      Y_predicted = classifier.predict(cv2_train_x)
      trainscores_folds.append(accuracy_score(cv2_train_y, Y_predicted))
      #
      classifier.fit(cv3_train_x,cv3_train_y)
      Y_predicted = classifier.predict(cv3_test_x)
      testscores_folds.append(accuracy_score(cv3_test_y, Y_predicted))
      Y_predicted = classifier.predict(cv3_train_x)
      trainscores_folds.append(accuracy_score(cv3_train_y, Y_predicted))
    trainscores.append(np.mean(np.array(trainscores_folds)))
    testscores.append(np.mean(np.array(testscores_folds)))
  return trainscores,testscores
```

My code is not clean and I want to have a cleaner version of this.
Note that,(1)The splitting should not be random and based on the index. (2) The n_neighbor values have been outside the function. please help me out with this.

Comment: So, what is your concrete question? You have already listed the steps you find necessary to make your code cleaner. If they don't work, please show us your code and why it failed.

Comment: So I wanted to know if there is a more efficient and tidy way to write the same code. I have written the code very explicitly so I want a cleaner version of this